Implementing WFS in OpenLayers 10.x
I'm relatively new to OpenLayers, and am struggling to get a WFS we serve to draw properly on my map. I have ImageWMS layers drawing successfully, but I was hoping to use a WFS, to then enable me to Zoom the map to the extent of Points selected with a filter to the WFS.
Below is the code I have, based on the OpenLayers examples (I've included an ID value which returns points in southern Ontario). The error I get is in ol.js:
Uncaught TypeError: t.getLayerStatesArray is not a function
I've searched for answers, but have not successfully figured out the issue. The WFS is publicly available, and is based on a virtual layer generated using Mapserver 8.x and GDAL/OGR sourced from a SQL Server table.
My ideal solution would be to add the points to the map, and then zoom the map to the extent of the points returning from the WFS. Currently, my WMS layer returns a map at full extent, as the GDAL/OGR virtual WMS layer does not limit the BBOX to the extent of the points, but rather to the default extent of the Mapserver layer.
var intStudyID = 764;

const LayerBackgroundCBMT = new ol.layer.Image({
    extent: [-141, 41, -52, 84],
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://maps.geogratis.gc.ca/wms/CBMT',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'CBMT' },
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'mapserver',
    }),
});

const LayerwmsCABINStudy = new ol.layer.Image({
    extent: [-141, 42, -52, 84],
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://cabin-rcba.ec.gc.ca/cabin/cabin_ows.asp',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'cabinstudy', 'intStudyID': intPassedStudyID },
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'mapserver',
    }),
});
    
const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.WFS(),
  url: function (extent) {
    return (
    'https://cabin-rcba.ec.gc.ca/cabin/cabin_ows.asp?' +
    'service=WFS&' +
      'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=cabinstudy&' +
      'intStudyID=' + intPassedStudyID +
      'srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
      'bbox=' +
      extent.join(',') +
      ',EPSG:4326'
    );
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bboxStrategy,
});

const vector = new ol.renderer.canvas.VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: {
    'stroke-width': 0.75,
    'stroke-color': 'white',
    'fill-color': 'rgba(100,100,100,0.25)',
  },
});

const layers = [LayerBackgroundCBMT, LayerwmsCABINStudy, vector];

const map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [-96, 49],
        zoom: 3,
    }),
});


vectorSource should be placed in a vector layer const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({

also WFS usually expects lat lon axis order for EPSG:4326 so you might need [extent[1], extent[0], extent[3], extent[2]].join(',')

The VectorSource is included in a Vector Layer further down in the code. What I'd like to do is establish an extent based on the points included in the layer, not the default extents of the layer as served by MapServer. A variable is used in the WFS call to limit the features returned, but the default extent is much larger.
